# How to download a cl_mem's element?

Tags: buffer, opencl

For example, I applied a cl_mem with a length of 7*sizeof(cl_int)

```
     cl_mem cl_test= clCreateBuffer
    (context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,7*sizeof(cl_int),NULL,NULL );
```

After some processing in the device, I want to download ONLY the third element instead of the whole cl_mem.

What can I do?

using

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue,cl_test[2],CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_int),(void*)data_int_host,0,NULL,NULL );
```

Or

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue,cl_test+2,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_int),(void*)data_int_host,0,NULL,NULL );
```

???
I don't know...

Thanks!

Comment: I should point out that using cl_test[2] or cl_test+2 can result in a segfault and should not be done since cl_test is a pointer to host-side memory that stores information about one, and only one, memory object in device-side memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `offset` parameter to the [clEnqueueReadBuffer()](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadBuffer.html) function.

For example, to read the third element of the buffer (assuming your buffer contains `cl_int`'s):

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, cl_test, CL_TRUE, 3 * sizeof(cl_int), sizeof(cl_int), (void*) data_int_host, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Simple answer, but hey, deserves a +1 :)